# Android: ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail return black bitmap

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-bitmap, android-videoview

I am dealing with the thumbnail in Android. Even though I use the function `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail` provided by Android, it gets black bitmap.

I start my research and find out some links: 
1/ [Thumbnail null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351228/thumbnailutils-createvideothumbnail-return-null-bitmap-for-mp4-file) 
2/ [Video Thumbnail return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303269/video-thumbnail-return-null)

However, I checked my returned bitmap and figure out that it is not null.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can Also do this , It's better approach I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/34082262/1462770

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to create Thumbnail

```
private Bitmap getThumbnailBitmap(String file_name,String file_type)
    {
        try
        {
            String file_path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+ Constants.APP_FOLDER_NAME+File.separator+ Constants.ATTACHMENTS_FOLDER_NAME+File.separator+file_name;
            if(file_type.equals(Constants.FILE_TYPE_IMAGE))
            {
                int dimens=(int) Env.currentActivity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.thumbnailHW);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file_path);
                Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(imageBitmap, dimens, dimens);

            }
            else if(file_type.equals(Constants.FILE_TYPE_VIDEO))
            {

                return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file_path, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have a try and mark it as an answer if it works.

Comment: I know exactly my input files are video and the code I use to get the thumbnail is exactly what you are using `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file_path, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);` Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This code create Thumbnail of video if you want create thumbnail of an image then use this code  ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file_path, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
Bitmap ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("picturePath", MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: Thank you for giving the answer. That function is exactly what i am doing to get the thumbnail. But I do not know why it return a black thumbnail.

Comment: did u check your video path?

Comment: all the videos i am store in a folder, but there are some video could not get the thumbnail, not all of them.

Comment: Yes, I did, all of them in .mp4. I wonder why there are only a few videos can have the thumbnail and the other return black thumbnail, not null. I get the thumbnail from the middle of the video and there is not a black frame so it should not be black thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

IF this method getThumbnailBitmap(); returns Bitmap  Null this issue occurs some devices so use below code

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                ContentUris.parseId(intent.getData()),
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                (BitmapFactory.Options) null );
```

Comment: I am able to receive the bitmap, but it is a black thumbnail. I get the thumbnail from the middle of the video and there is an image so it should not be black